# MYSQL: Where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm covering the basics and I've ran into an error.  I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM monday, tuesday WHERE games_won=3 AND games_drawn=1
```

And getting this error:

`Column 'games_won' in where clause is ambiguous.`

I know it's got something to do with both tables having the same field name, so the the query won't accept it, but I'm just not sure the correct SQL to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: What is in the monday and tuesday columns, and what do you want your query to return?

Comment: As the error says it: as it appears you have the same columns in both tables, so mysql wouldn't know which one to use if you don't specify one!

Comment: show table structure of both tables and tell two columns belongs to which table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give proper alias names to query. Give alias name of particular table to columns

```
 SELECT * FROM monday mon, tuesday tue 
 where mon.games_won=3 AND tue.games_drawn=1
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this has solved my issue.  I will accept your answer when the time allows me to.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention, your query is failing because MySQL doesn't know which `games_won` column to use.

You can tell it explicitly:

```
SELECT * FROM monday, tuesday 
WHERE monday.games_won=3 AND monday.games_drawn=1 AND tuesday.games_won=3 AND tuesday.games_drawn=1
```

However I suspect this wont give the behaviour you want. This will perform a join of the two tables so if you have:

```
Monday                           Tuesday
|id |games_won|games_drawn|      |id |games_won|games_drawn|
|1  |3        |1          |      |3  |3        |1          |
|2  |3        |1          |      |4  |3        |1          |
```

This will give:

```
Results
|id |games_won|games_drawn|id |games_won|games_drawn|
|1  |3        |1          |3  |3        |1          |
|1  |3        |1          |4  |3        |1          |
|2  |3        |1          |3  |3        |1          |
|2  |3        |1          |4  |3        |1          |
```

Which is a full join of the tables.

I assume that you want a list of rows from each table that match the WHERE. In this case you can UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM monday WHERE games_won=3 AND games_drawn=1
UNION
SELECT * FROM tuesday WHERE games_won=3 AND games_drawn=1
```

Finally it's unusual to have a table for each day. You can simplify your database by storing the day in a game_results table:

```
game_results
    id
    games_won
    games_drawn
    day
```

This makes it easier to check results over different days.

Comment: Wow, this is an incredibly detailed explanation.  Much appreciated!  Also, a good idea to use an extra field to specify the day.  I will use this in the future.